# What is the limit on how high you can fly up?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, flight, aarakocra

I was playing an [Aarakocra](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/aarakocra) in a non-Adventurers-League-game. I noticed that there is no height limitation on flight in 5e, so I could **hypothetically** fly out of the range of virtually everything and defeat anything by dropping bombs on it repeatedly.

Is there a limit on the height you might attain by flying? Could you literally fly into space this way?

If there was no limit on height, I could use a 1st-level Aarakocra of any class on a Tarrasque and kill it (very slowly) with repeated bombs and the like while taking no damage.

This is ridiculously overpowered if there are no limits on how high I can fly up.

Comment: There seem to be 2 (almost entirely) independent questions in there: 1. A warlock being able to defeat a Tarrasque by blasting it with *Eldrich Blast* from a safe distance and 2. The limitations on Aarakocra flight (altitude). It may be best to seperate these questions or clearly indicate that you're not asking about the Achilles Heel of a Tarrasque, but only want to include this as an example of a ridiculous situation that could be the result of the lack of limitations...

Comment: True, and I have changed that back to my original bombing idea. The Aarokocra might have to resupply, but, done with enough caution, could still never get hit. I just wanted to use the Tarrasque scenario as an extreme example.

Comment: Related question: [*How can I, as a DM, keep an Aarakocra player in check?*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/116914/how-can-i-as-a-dm-keep-an-aarakocra-player-in-check)

Comment: Posting a “Related” question doesn’t mean “here is your answer”, it means it’s related. It adds it to this question’s list of related questions in the database, to make it easier for readers to find related questions. (It is clearly related.)

Comment: @TheCentaur you should feel free to ask the Eldrich Blast question in a separate post!  Both are interesting questions.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. You're asking two entirely separate questions here: "How high can I fly" and "is it overpowered to fly really high". The first question is a simple rules question, the second requires a lot more analysis. I suggest you remove the part about infinite flight being overpowered and ask that question separately.

Comment: @DuckTapeAl OP makes a statment.about balance, but there is no question about balance.

Comment: @DuckTapeAl This seems to be a case of "perceived inequities between characters." hence the balance tag.

Comment: What do you mean by "bombs"?

Answer (score 5):

### RAW there is no specified limit, however, the general rules of movement and travel apply with their risks.

You have not specified a setting with established rules, hence this will be general. Your DM will narrate the world and they will think of such things as "Is there such a place as space", "When does space start?", all things that make for the rules of that world are established and narrated by your DM. In 5e we have no tables that define how long you can see things in detail, only that you can even discern fine detail up to a mile when you have **The Aspect of the Beast: Eagle** (PHB 50).

You will have to ask your DM how high you can fly and drop objects with accuracy or even see creatures for that matter. You may be able to see as far as 40 miles, but perhaps there is always fog or clouds in the sky that will obscure your vision.

**Visibility Outdoors** (DMG 243):

> When traveling outdoors, characters can see about 2 miles in any
>   direction on a clear day, or until the point where trees, hills, or
>   other obstructions block their view. Rain normally cuts maximum
>   visibility down to 1 mile, and fog can cut it down to between 100 and
>   300 feet. On a clear day, the characters can see 40 miles if they are
>   atop a mountain or a tall hill, or are otherwise able to look down on
>   the area around them from a height.

The sky is a place with encounters like any other place, but you will be able to stay out of range of most creatures.

**The Sky** (DMG 119-120):

> Flying characters can move from one place to another in a relatively
>   straight line, ignoring terrain and monsters that can't fly or that
>   lack ranged attacks.
>   Flying by spell or magic item works the same as travel on foot, as described in the Player's Handbook.
>
> As adventurers travel through the air, check for random encounters as
>   you normally would. lgnore any result that indicates a non-flying
>   monster, unless the characters are flying close enough to the ground
>   to be targeted by non-flying creatures making ranged attacks.
>   Characters have normal chances to spot creatures on the ground and can
>   decide whether to engage them.

So you may face encounters on your way towards space if there is such a thing in your DMs world. And you have the normal travelling pace, see **Travel Pace** (PHB 181). And as you are a first-level Aarakocra I will assumme that you have no gear or means to avoid **Exhaustion** (PHB 181, 185, 291), so you will eventually fall to your death. That is if your DM didn't come up with hazards such as thin-air, air-currents, etc. that prevented you from flying as far up as you want.

Or perhaps your DM enjoys your idea and will provide you with a little hut in the clouds, that has endless support of rocks to drop on your enemies, while you sit in your stronghold and giggle at their demise.

You will have to get the things that you drop on your enemies somewhere because you have a [limited carrying capacity](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76758/how-much-weight-can-an-aarakocra-carry-when-flying), but this is one of the reasons why the ability to fly is considered very powerful. You can solve a lot of encounters easily, especially if you are playing one on one.

The other hazard that you will eventually face is **High Altitude** (DMG 110):

> Traveling at altitudes of 10,000 feet or higher above sea level is
>   taxing for a creature that needs to breathe, because of the reduced
>   amount of oxygen in the air. Each hour such a creature spends
>   traveling at high altitude counts as 2 hours for the purpose of
>   determining how long that creature can travel. Breathing creatures can
>   become acclimated to a high altitude by spending 30 days or more at
>   this elevation. Breathing creatures can't become acclimated to
>   elevations above 20,000 feet unless they are native to such
>   environments.

High altitude will severely impact the upward-progress that you make and gives insight into some of the expected boundaries by game-design. Perhaps you want your tiny hut with an endless supply of rocks here between 10,000-20,000 feet, where you still can get acclimated without being native to the area.